# In Python, how to read through lines in a text file and produce two different output files for whether keywords exist and do not exist

Tags: python, string, list, file, text

**Problem**: There's a list of keywords. I'm trying to read lines in a text file in which all sentences sit on a different line, and if one of the keywords exists in any of the lines, I want to delete that line from the file, create a new text file, and paste it in there. Then save the remaining lines in another file.

I've tried `else` and `elif` statements as well as the `Queue`module, but keep getting random duplicate lines with and without keywords in both output files.

I also haven't been able to find a method that will enable the loop to also count the words in UPPERCASE, keywords with Initials Capitalized, and the plural forms of the keywords. Hence the messy look in the list below.

My latest attempt was:

```
fileToSearch = "Test file to search keywords from.txt"
fileToContainOnlyKeywords = "Only Keywords.txt"
fileToContainNoKeywords = "No Keywords.txt"

listOfKeywords = ['one', 'One', 'ONE', 'ones', 'two', 'Two', 'TWO']

f_output_1 = open(fileToContainOnlyKeywords, 'w')
f_output_2 = open(fileToContainNoKeywords, 'w')

with open(fileToSearch,'r') as f_input:
  listOfAllLines = f_input.readlines()
  for line in listOfAllLines:
    for keyword in listOfKeywords:
      keywordFound = keyword in line
      if keywordFound:
        f_output_1.write(line)
  for line in listOfAllLines:
    for keyword in listOfKeywords:
      keywordFound = keyword in line
      if not keywordFound:
        f_output_2.write(line)
print("Done.")
```

Inside the original text file (Test file to search keywords from.txt) looks like this:

```
Solving one problem at a time is the key. # keyword
One way to solve this exists and I only need to find it. # keyword with initial capitalized
Solving four problems at a time is the bad way to go. # no keyword
I'm a sentence containing the keyword TWO, so I should be in the second file. # keyword
This is another sentence without keywords and it needs to be in the third file. # no keyword
```

I've been trying different ways to write this and I've read dozens of pages on Stack and other places, haven't been able to find the solution. So, please help this poor beginner of Python.

Thanks in advance and happy coding!

Comment: You can shorten your list of keywords by using `keywordFound = keyword.upper() in line.upper()` to convert things to uppercase. You can also remove the `f_output_2` loop by using [an `else` block](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements) instead of 2 separate `if` statements in 2 separate loops. You can also remove `readlines` as it's normal to loop over lines of a text file using `for line in f_input:`.

Comment: As for plurals, that's another matter entirely. After all, some words ending in 's' aren't plurals, like "its", while others end in "-es" (boxes, foxes) or "-en" (oxen), though not all words ending in those letter sequences are plurals (fasten, mashes). You should probably consider singular and plural forms as if they're entirely different words.